# Julia memoized code for Fuss-Catalan numbers

Tags: algorithm, julia, memoization

From the Fuss-Catalan series C{4}_n (see the Online Encyclopedia for Integer Sequences [OEIS A002293](https://oeis.org/A002293)), I'd like to calculate the nth term using memoization. The code I cooked up below works, but takes about 43s when n=200 on my laptop. Is there a way to speed this up further?

```
numterms = 20
C4 = Array{BigInt}(numterms+1) # memoization dictionary
fill!(C4,-1) # -1 implies not yet computed
C4[1] = 1 # Base case for n=0, C[n+1] provides nth term

function catalan4(n,C)
    C[n+1] == -1 || return C[n+1]
    sum1 = convert(BigInt,0)
    for i in 1:n
       sum2 = convert(BigInt,0)
       for j in 1:(n-i+1)
            sum3 = convert(BigInt,0)
            for k in 1:(n-i-j+2)
                sum3+= catalan4(k-1,C)*catalan4(n-i-j-k+2,C)
            end
            sum2 +=  catalan4(j-1,C)*sum3          
       end
       sum1 +=  catalan4(i-1,C)*sum2 
    end
    C[n+1] = sum1    
    return sum1
end 

for i in 1:numterms
    println(i,"\t",catalan4(i,C4))
end
```

This provides as expected:

```
1   1
2   4
3   22
4   140
5   969
6   7084
7   53820
8   420732
9   3362260
10  27343888
11  225568798
12  1882933364
13  15875338990
14  134993766600
15  1156393243320
16  9969937491420
17  86445222719724
18  753310723010608
19  6594154339031800
20  57956002331347120
```

Thanks!

Comment: While I haven't benchmarked your code, my guess is that the most important thing is to declare `C` as `const`. Avoid mutable global variables.

Comment: I add the const keyword ahead of C - didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, I see, it is being passed as an argument.

Comment: It seems that there is an explicit formula for these numbers?

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a formula to count the number of node arrangements when the trees are infinitely long. However, when the trees are restricted to a given depth, a  slightly more complicated recursion holds which doesn't seem to have a closed form. I'm trying to use this simpler example to learn how to speed up the memoization for the restricted tree case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after Stefan's answer above -  I tried a couple of things. To see if the cuplrit was really Julia's BigInt, I tried the GMP mpz_t integers in a C version of the above code. Indeed, it was about 10 times faster for n=200. However, I sometimes need n=4096, and GMP and C wasn't really going to help me cut down my compute time. I then noticed that the inner loops were also being repeatedly re-calculated. So I memoized both the inner sums as follows, and now the code gives me for n=200, evaluation times of 0.06 seconds (down from 43s) with Julia and BigInts!

```
numterms = 200
C4 = Array{BigInt}(numterms+1) # memoization dictionary
fill!(C4,-1) # -1 implies not yet computed
C4[1] = 1 # Base case for n=0, C[n+1] provides nth term

# memoize partial sums as well
sum2store = similar(C4)
sum3store = similar(C4)
fill!(sum2store, -1)
fill!(sum3store, -1)

function catalan4(n,C)
    C[n+1] == -1 || return C[n+1]
    sum1 = convert(BigInt,0)
    for i in 1:n
        if sum2store[n-i+1] == -1
            sum2 = convert(BigInt,0)
            for j in 1:(n-i+1)
                if sum3store[n-i-j+2] == -1
                    sum3 = convert(BigInt,0)
                    for k in 1:(n-i-j+2)
                        sum3+= catalan4(k-1,C)*catalan4(n-i-j-k+2,C)
                    end
                    sum3store[n-i-j+2] = sum3
                end
                sum2 +=  catalan4(j-1,C)*sum3store[n-i-j+2]
            end
            sum2store[n-i+1] = sum2
        end
        sum1 +=  catalan4(i-1,C)*sum2store[n-i+1]
    end
    C[n+1] = sum1
    return sum1
end
```

Now I don't need Julia's BigInt to be fast - I'm just happy I can use it.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you got that working faster. The fastest computation is the one you don't do :)

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that bad `BigInt` performance is the culprit here. You might want to try [Nemo](http://nemocas.org/), which uses the [Flint library](http://flintlib.org/) for arbitrary precision integers, which I understand is considerably more efficient. If you want to stay in standard Julia (Nemo is Julia-based, but differs from Julia in some language semantics, afaik – it's a computer algebra system) and your numbers are limited to being smaller than 2^127, then you could try using `Int128` instead – these can be stack-allocated and kept in registers, unlike `BigInts`, which must be heap-allocated and which LLVM doesn't know how to reason about (it can't transform creation of new `BigInts` into mutation of existing ones). It might not be too hard to create custom `Int256` and `Int512` types that use two/four `Int128` values to do their arithmetic, especially if you only need to support addition and multiplication.

Comment: I think that's it - but I don't think I know how to do this without seeing an example. Could you point me in the direction of how to create a new bitstype made of _m_ Int128 values with the * operation defined over it?

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/simonbyrne/DoubleDouble.jl/blob/master/src/DoubleDouble.jl; that's probably more complicated than using a pair of UInt128 values to represent a UInt256 would be. You shouldn't really have to roll this yourself though. The BigInts in base Julia should be more efficient – we'd like them to be but it's not the top priority, I'm afraid.